# Delete angular controller/service to regain memory in single page application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I am building a single page application using ANGULAR. I am trying to load necessary JS files for each page on demand.

For ex, for page1, JS1 will be loaded and when page2 is loaded through angular, I want to download JS2 and remove JS1. By doing so, I can regain the memory used by JS1.

Is there any way to make angular controller/service to destroy itself and instantiate again?

Also, is there any other way to regain the memory?

Comment: How many js you have in project ?

Comment: There will be around 3 files per page and user can go upto 6 pages in application. Each file will be around 100KB.

Comment: I will recommend you concatenating and minifying files into one file better  then deleting js hacks

Comment: I am more concerned about memory footprint that is left in page than the size of JS files. We will load the JS files after minification and concatenation only.

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't support what you are talking about, out of the box. You have to do some major modifications to make this work. An example of this is here https://github.com/ifyio/angularjs-lazy-loading-with-requirejs.

Other than something like this, that will have problems eventually, Angular doesn't support Lazy loading. With Angular's Dependency Injection, it is extremely difficult to add Lazy Loading.

Comment: Thanks. I will check out this library.

Answer (score 1):

I remember the same problem in my project and there are many files that are called at once ikn my angularapp, but 2-3 of them are not essential for a single page to render and as the partial changes the need of 2-3 files ends and new need is generated.

so i have amnipulated the code in a manner, such that i have included the js files or css files respective to the code in the partial itself, so if 1 partial is called it brings it's js, css and other files with itself, this reduces the scope.